# Get all problems (errors, warnings, etc.) using VSCode extensions API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a VSCode extension and I need a way to access all of the current errors, warnings, etc in the Problems pane but I am not even sure if the API provides access to this. I see that I can create `Diagnostics` and it appears that I can get those diagnostics with the `DiagnosticCollection` but I don't see where I can get a list of all of the errors and such. Does anyone have experience with this.

p.s. I have tried

```
console.log(vscode.DiagnosticCollection) // undefined
console.log(vscode) // Looked through the object and found nothing of use
console.log(window) // Same thing. Nothing of use.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation seems like it's not possible at the moment.
but I saw some discussions on adding an API to the problem view so that might be available in one of the next versions.

Comment: I am thinking at this point you are correct. Maybe they will open it up soon.

Answer (score 2):

There are now 2 api's for this, see [api reference: language diagnostics](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages):

`getDiagnostics(): [Uri, Diagnostic[]][]` get diagnostics for all files

```js
let diagnostics = vscode.languages.getDiagnostics();
```

`getDiagnostics(resource: Uri): Diagnostic[]` get the diagnostics for a specific uri

```js
const uri = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri;
let diagnostics = vscode.languages.getDiagnostics(uri);  // returns an array
```